# Free Javascript+Jquery IDE ? Features like - intellisense etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide

I am looking for JavaScript IDE that is good and free.
I have read many post of stackoverflow itself, asking same question but most of the tools suggested are paid.
eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support

**But I am looking specifically and free IDE.**

Comment: What specific features would you like from your IDE (please update your question)?  In addition, should it support PHP or other server-side code?  I suggest differentiating your question with specifics otherwise it's a duplicate.

Comment: From your link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/209134/437226

Comment: Notepad++ text editor for Windows is all you need. They added `workspaces` in latest versions which make it closer to a IDE.

Comment: ya but the accepted and from this is aptana .. I used it.. but it doesn't seem friendly ... its is very heavy , loading take time.. have u personally used it ? What are ur reviews ?

Comment: I personally love it.  It is based on Eclipse, but I am able to keep my web programming separated from my other development (I use the standalone version, but it's available as an Eclipse plugin).  It also has FTP support built in, which is nifty.

The startup time is about ten seconds, which leaves something to be desired, but otherwise I don't have any issues with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Eclipse for all my non-.NET coding. Mostly PHP/JS/jQuery and XUL/JS. It doesn't have autocompletion for jQuery though. Many people recommend Aptana since it does have jQuery support, however overall Aptana performed far slower and was buggy, so I just use plain Eclipse, but YMMV.

Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org
Aptana: http://www.aptana.com

EDIT: There are plugins that may add jQuery support to Eclipse. Here's one: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/58952 I last searched for one about a year ago and didn't find any, but I might try installing this one at work tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue not very long ago. While I personally now chose the not-very-expensive Jetbrains' Webstorm (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), another VERY close contender was the Aptana, and Komodo Edit - as I was initially looking for a free IDE/Editor as well. I sometimes still use Komodo Edit for some rather tiny and quick things.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is the best option for you. It is free and has plugins to support most of the programming languages. The intellisense for javascript and jQuery is also there.

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Answer (score 1):

For the beginner, [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) is my suggestion. Basically it's Eclipse focused to the web. And since it's eclipse-based, eclipse plugins will work on it also. It has auto-complete support for HTML5, CSS3, JS, PHP and many others i don't use.

For speed, i suggest [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with it's Explorer plugin and BeSpin Theme (for a similar feel to Aptana).

All of which don't have jQuery autocomplete though but you can have a quick look-up using [jQuery's dynamic API Browser](http://api.jquery.com/browser/) (Also available as an AIR app)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers is free, and will help you.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime text edito](http://www.sublimetext.com/)r with [jquery plug-in for sublime](https://github.com/mrmartineau/jQuery) is all that is required

Follow these steps if you are manually installing the plug-in

After you have installed sublime text editor

1. Create a jQuery folder  (in 'Packages' folder)
2. copy the snippets to this folder
3. auto-completion would work in any .js file

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't free-to-use, but after you purchased it for 70 bucks.